# The dimension of the array of an image is 3D not 2D as it is in the Python course

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, multidimensional-array

In my python course, the instructor uploads a greyscale picture of himself and reads it on Python with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import math
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

im = Image.open("chris.tiff")
array = np.array(im)

print(array.shape)
```

and he gets

```
(200,200)
```

When I write the code and run my own image, with the exact same extension "tiff", I get a 3-dimensional array. I was told it's because my image was colored and so the third entry is for RBG. So I used a greyscale photo just like he did but I still obtain a 3D array, why?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

**EDIT**

For extra clarity, the array I get for my greyscale image with tiff extension is

```
(3088, 2316, 4)
```

Comment: What is the dimension that you get on the grey image? Is it `(200, 200, 1)`? If yes, then it's the same as your teacher's image.

Comment: good point @Anwarvic but I get ```python3

(3088, 2316, 4)

```

Comment: Could you upload the image to the question? We need to reproduce the case

Comment: @Anwarvic done!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Upload the image to GoogleDrive for example and provide the link. I need it to be `tiff` as the question

Comment: I think you converted the image to grayscale but still saved as a color image. Which software do you use?

Comment: https://ibb.co/7YVxDzv @Anwarvic

Comment: @ThomasWeller  You're right my first try was converting, but then i took a greyscale picture with my iPhone, that should do the trick no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your photo appears to be grey, but actually, it has the three channels based on the posted shape.

So, you need to convert it to greyscale using the following line:

```
im = Image.open("chris.tiff").convert('L')
```

Comment: MY GOODNESS, THANK YOU! This worked super well How can a photo appear to be greyscale and not be greyscale?

Comment: Grey is also a color. An image taken at night is also black, but your camera doesn't know that. So it will still save it with color information - although there is none.

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you from the bottom of my heart, this was eating me up inside

Comment: I think when a grey image has three channels, we call it `RGB Grey` which is different than `Greyscale`